# JMeter Error - java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF-8

Tags: jmeter

[image]I am getting below error through jmeter while replaying a weburl. same url is working fine in browsers.
PFB for error detail.

> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.HTMLParseException:
>   java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException:  UTF-8  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser.getEmbeddedResourceURLs(LagartoBasedHtmlParser.java:233)

Please provide solution to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to this comma after the `UTF-8`

[image]

Try [running JMeter as](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override):

```
jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx
```

and it should resolve your issue. If this is the case - check *system.properties* file for the following entry:

```
file.encoding=UTF-8,
```

and remove the trailing comma from there.

More information on JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

Also I wasn't able to reproduce your issue even by passing incorrect encodings using latest [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) so make sure to perform the upgrade if you're using an older version

Comment: I tried running jmeter using above mention command....still getting same error.
Also, I did not get anything like "file.encoding=UTF-8," as you mention above in system.properties......there is properties "sampleresult.default.encoding" in jmeter.properties.